# Click on iframe element using Python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, iframe, cross-domain

How can I click the red button [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ms313/H8VJv/) from Host A (in this example jsfiddle.net) using selenium python? (javascript limitation policy error do not let me do it). Also I do not want to click directly **Red Button**.
Thanks.

> el =driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/input")
> webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).click(el).perform()

iframe that keeps red button:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.myhostb.blogfa.com/" width="500" height="300">
</iframe>
```

Important note: imaging that jsfiddle.net is Host A.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `switch_to_frame()`

```
driver.switch_to_frame("result")
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body>iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ex2").click()
```

Once you're done in the `iframe`, you can switch back to the top frame using:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: @mohsensolhnia The example above should work with the HTML example you provided.  As for the "same domain policy", I have no idea what that refers to, and I don't appreciate you yelling at me, particularly when I don't see "same domain policy" in your original question.

Comment: i got error `Message: unknown error: Error is not a function`

Comment: @BudiMulyo If you have a question, I would highly recommend that you create a new one, with code examples, the HTML you are trying to access, and the complete error message, in the Selenium tag.  I would gladly take a look and see if I can help you with it.

Comment: @Richard thanks for reply, but it was solved using `wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='mainframe']")))`